# How to add components using loop in Eagle PCB script?

Tags: eaglecad

Eagle command language contains the ADD function but not loops. Eagle ULP contains loops but no function to add a component. Under these circumstances, how does one add components e.g a lot of LEDs into a schematic using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use a ULP to execute editor commands, but only in a very non-obvious way:
The built-in `exit()` function can be given a string that is executed immediately after the ULP has exited:

```
exit("ADD whatever...");
```

See the file `cmd-draw.ulp` for a complete example.

Comment: How about this, first we use ULP to get input from user on how many LED he wants. Then we create a string and pass it to exit(), then we use another script that is automatically called to rotate and move each of those LEDs. Is this possible?

Comment: You would use a single script that creates the LEDs at the correct places to begin with.